# WP Site not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Could anyone please come to solve problem braintreegate.com. I have designed using Word Press. It now shows "Fatal Error".

After activating some plugins like "Gust", "Magee Shortcodes", "Wordfence Security"., then it shows some unsolvable error.

Thanks & Regards,
Karamvir

Comment: As the error message says, you're trying to call function get() on non-object. Usually (but not always) this happens when the caller is NULL due to some previous logic error.

Answer (score 0):

As from your comment: *After activating some plugins like "Gust", "Magee Shortcodes", "Wordfence Security"., then it shows some unsolvable error.*

Please deactivat all above plugins temporarily to see if this resolves the problem (plugin functions can interfere). If this works, re-activate them individually (one-by-one) to find the problematic plugin(s).

Once catch that problematic plugin, turn on `WP_DEBUG` to see if there's any other error? And take action on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But admin panel is also inaccessible.

Comment: What if you try to open this into other PC?

Comment: So how to accomplish that?